# sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation

Tags: ssh, connection

I have tried every possible piece of command I could lay my hands on.  I still get this.  I spun a digital ocean droplet with ubuntu 16.04 on it.  I followed the tutorial until I had to login in again as the new user. I am at my wits end trying to find a solution.
This is the output if I give the command ssh-add

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Comment: You say you followed 'the tutorial' can you post a link or relevant article(s). We'll likely need more info about your config help you out.

Answer (score 15):

I think your ssh-agent isn't working!
Perform the following commands...

```
eval `ssh-agent -s` 
ssh-add
```

Comment: For me, I had generated a new SSH key over the top of the old one, and had to run `ssh-add` to get the system to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This may indicate file permission problems to your `~/.gnupg` directory and underlying files!

Also make sure you have valid `pinentry` installed and operational, otherwise cannot validate PIN to your smartcard and this problem will occur as well!

The example `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` should look like this:

```
enable-ssh-support
pinentry-program /Applications/MacPorts/pinentry-mac.app/Contents/MacOS/pinentry-mac
```

After changes are made to the configuration remember to `gpgconf --reload`.

Answer (score 1):

For **gpg2.1**

`SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK`