# SSH Key only working with ssh agent

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent

I just created a set of SSH keys and used `ssh-copy-id` to copy it on to a remote server.

Upon trying to connect via `ssh` I got the error

> `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation`

Similarly, when trying to connect via MOSH I get asked for a passphrase even though these keys were made without a passphrase at all.

All of the permissions on my `.ssh` folder (and my home directory) were set to `700`.

Looking at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1102133/sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation) led me to try

> I think your ssh-agent isn't working ! Perform the following commands...

```
    eval ssh-agent -s 
    ssh-add
```

which immediately made the login work.  The problem with this is that I do not want to always have to use ssh-agent, MOSH itself does not support SSH-Agent and so I am wondering if there is a way I can make my keys work without using `ssh-agent`.  Can somebody explain to me if this is possible.

Note: The remote computer in this case is a Raspberry  PI running Pidora.

Comment: `ssh username@ipaddress`  Also, the other way, with mosh, was just by opening the chrome app and typing in the username and password

Comment: For mosh there is only one way to upload a key, and only one at a time so yes it knows which key to use.  The name of my key file, used in both, is just `id_rsa`

Comment: your permissions might still be wrong e.g. some should be 644 see alex's answer here http://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder

Comment: I don't like *ssh-agent* either, and do not use it. I have the usual *config* file in *~/.ssh*, with the keys associated to the hosts, and also the usual instruction *IdentitiesOnly yes* for all hosts. Of course, this means I have to type in the key password every time, which does not bother me.